# Mongodump cannot specify username and uri

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodump

I had the following command but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
mongodump --uri="130.164.10.1:27017,130.164.10.2:27017,130.164.10.3:27017/?replicaSet=rs0" -d mydb -u admin -p myPass -o C:\myDump
```

I am using mongodb 4.2. I got error "cannot specify --username and --uri". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The URI already includes credentials and the database, so either use the `--uri` option and provide the credentials and database name in the URI or use the `-d -u -p` options along with `--host` etc.

The URI structure is explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

Try:

```
--uri="mongodb://admin:myPass@130.164.10.1:27017,130.164.10.2:27017,130.164.10.3:27017/mydb?replicaSet=rs0"
```

Comment: Do you mind converting my above command into the valid uri structure you mention? Thanks a lot :)